# Storing current time without milliseconds component

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a timespan object that needs to hold only time, without date. I would use

```
DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
```

but the problem is it gives time in the format

```
15:51:51.7368329
```

I don't want the milliseconds component. How can I trim it out?

Comment: Is this just about display to the user, or do you genuinely need to turn this into another timespan with the milliseconds component stripped out?

Comment: yeah, I guess its only about displaying, so I'll just go with the ToString() method

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can either use `DateTime.Now.Hour/Minute/Second` properties or you could use `DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")`.

Refer here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

Comment: The "h:mm:ss" will not give the desired result. `h` represents the 1-digit representation of non-military hours, and `mm` represents the 2-digit representation of the current month. Therefore, this would give 3:02:51 for the example provided, instead of 15:51:51, as requested.

Comment: I think you should have a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: I think MM represents month, while mm represents minutes.

Answer (score 8):

Simply subtract away the millisecond part:

```
DateTime myTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
myTime = myTime.AddMilliseconds(-myTime.Millisecond);
```

It could be done in less code, without first assigning to `myTime`:

```
DateTime myTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.AddMilliseconds(
  -DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Millisecond);
```

Although somewhat elegant, it is a bad idea. When accessing `TimeOfDay` twice, there is a chance that it at some point will have passed another millisecond before the second access. In that case the result would not be zero milliseconds.

Comment: your first line won't compile.

Answer (score 8):

I believe this is what you may be after:

```
TimeSpan timeNow = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan trimmedTimeNow = new TimeSpan(timeNow.Hours, timeNow.Minutes, timeNow.Seconds);
```

Comment: I prefer this to going to a string and back.

Comment: With regards to performance, I think mrcrowl's suggestion is better than to to string and back. I think it is about 9 times faster (both are fast however).

Answer (score 5):

If the problem is displaying it, you can do this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx As per .NET.. MM represents month and not minute.

Comment: @Mohib: you are absolutely right. Updated accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. When displaying to user you can specify needed format. Here is a good tutorial:

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

1. You can create new DateTime object passing to constructor only hour, minute, second (it's for saving.)

Answer (score 1):

You can  use this function to check what format suits you:

```
DateTime.Now.GetDateTimeFormats();
```

This will give you all the Formats like:

- `"14/05/2011"`
- `"14/05/11"`
- `"14.05.11"`
- `"14-05-11"`
- `"2011-05-14"`
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this-

```
DateTime.Parse(
                DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"),
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
              );
```

Worked for me :).